# Hide link inJSQMessageViewController Bubble

Tags: objective-c, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Is there a way to hide a link in a text inside the messageBubble? I don't need it!

Is there some settings to set, for example:

```
disableLink = true
```

Thanks a lot for the reply!

Comment: Is the link in a specific property? If yes, just disable the property, indeed. But if your link is just text among text in the message, as I guess it is, then there's no magic. ;) You'll have to regex the thing out.

Comment: the problem is that there is an automatic conversion in JSQMessage from simple text from hyperlink and i want to disable it

Comment: I don't know where is the `UITextView` in `JSQMessage` SDK, but `[textView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeNone];`, or if you just want to disable the link but keep the others:`[textView setDataDetectorTypes:(UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber|UIDataDetectorTypeLink|UIDataDetectorTypeAddress|UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent)];`

Comment: Try changing the attributes of the JSQMessagesCellTextView `linkTextAttributes` property so that it no longer is a "link" but just text. Like: remove underline, detectable, etc.

Answer (score 1):

within JSQMessagesCellTextView.h

set

```
self.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
```

also within JSQMessagesViewController.m
line 543 is set to

```
     cell.textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

has to be (example)

```
     cell.textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAddress;
```